# How can I change the Ethernet (IPv4) properties from my Android phone?

Tags: settings, connection-issues, 8.0-oreo, ip-address, google-pixel-2

So my problem is: I am currently writing an Android application which has to get access on data sent via Ethernet connection. The app is going to replace a Windows tool which is able to receive data from another (automotive) device sent via Ethernet. When using this Windows tool, I have to change my computers Network Settings like shown below, so that the tool is able to set up a connection to the device:

Local Area Connection - Properties - TCP/IPv4 - Properties - change IP adress and subnet mask to the values which fit to the device

Now I want my application to receive the Ethernet signals. I am using a Google Pixel 2 with Android 8.0 and also have an USB-C to Ethernet adapter. I already tried to get an Ethernet connection by connecting to the Internet with an Ethernet cable plugged into my phone (with the adapter of course). So that means, receiving data via Ethernet should be theoretically possible. But I do not know, how I can change my phones Ethernet settings. The phones Ethernet controller also has to apply this certain IP address but there are no options in my phone's menu.

Do you guys know any way how I can change the phone's Ethernet settings/properties?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)